# Snapping coordinates/points across different layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, editing, snapping, vertices

I'm referring to the plugin that was Numerical Vertex Edit where it selected the nearest point in one layer and allowed for a copy and paste to another layer's any given point to match its coordinates. Unfortunately, that plugin has crashed in 2.16.0 version, doesn't snap points accurately across layers anymore on older version and is no longer supported by the author. As far as I can tell, there's no replacement tool that allows for the same easiness of duplicating the same coordinates across different layers.

The problem is I have about 52,000 points to adjust from my layer to another and manually dragging with the Node tool is not time efficient.

Does anyone have any recommendations of a similar tool/plugin I can use or even some kind of code I can look into?

First picture shows what I want it to do but with the greatest accuracy and time efficiency. Second picture shows the original.

[image]
[image: want to adjust mid point of blue layer to exactly one of the points on black layer]